# Is there any way to find the value of a query?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently made a system that ranks each players depending on their points. Well the way the system gets the points is rather confusing. After using this system for over 24 hours, I have found out that it is not organizing it according to the points. But then it suddenly occurred to me, that I could be calculating the points wrong in a way that does not represent the SQL query. Here is my SQL query that my rankings uses:

```
SELECT * , playeruid AS player_id, (
(
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(player1points),0) 
    FROM  `mybb_matches` 
    WHERE player1uid = player_id AND gid = $id AND timestamp < $time AND winneruid is NOT NULL AND dispute != 3 )
+
(
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(player2points),0) 
    FROM  `mybb_matches` 
    WHERE player2uid = player_id AND gid = $id AND timestamp < $time AND winneruid is NOT NULL AND dispute != 3 )
+
(
    SELECT SUM( rank ) 
    FROM  `mybb_matchesgame` 
    WHERE playeruid = player_id AND gid = $id )
)

 AS points
 FROM mybb_matchesgame WHERE gid = $id
 ORDER BY points DESC
```

Now that this is shown, I was wondering if there's any way to grab the value of "points" and display it somehow so I can verify the number. Is this possible?

Comment: `not organizing it according to the points` -- but you have `ORDER BY points DESC`??  `grab the value of "points"` -- but you have `SELECT`??  In other words, I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to make sure the query is working. I want to verify the "points" gathered by the query for every user is correct. Is there a way I can grab this number of "points"? Perhaps echo it out somewhere?

Comment: Do the individual sub-queries work as expected if you execute them directly in phpmyadmin or in mysql command line interface? And inside the sub-queries, is `player_id` the current value from the main table `mybb_matchesgame`? If so try adding an alias to the main table: `FROM mybb_matchesgame m WHERE gid = $id` and then use it to prefix the other values, ie `WHERE player1uid = m.player_id`

Comment: What;s the problem? Get it just as any other field names. If you have something like $row, just do $row['points']

Answer (score 0):

There are no group by statements in the queries, so the SUM is most likely not over the expected set. Also COALESCE can be replaced with IFNULL, which might be a bit more efficient.

```
SELECT q.* , playeruid AS player_id, a.points+b.points+c.points AS points
FROM mybb_matchesgame q
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM(player1points),0) as points,player_id
    FROM  `mybb_matches` 
    WHERE timestamp < $time AND winneruid is NOT NULL AND dispute != 3 
 GROUP BY player_id) a ON player1uid = a.player_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(sum(player2points),0) as points,player_id
    FROM  `mybb_matches` 
    WHERE timestamp < $time AND winneruid is NOT NULL AND dispute != 3 
GROUP BY player_id) b ON player2uid = b.player_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT IFNULL(SUM( rank ),0) as points,player_id
    FROM  `mybb_matchesgame` 
GROUP BY player_id) c ON playeruid = c.player_id 
  WHERE gid = $id
 ORDER BY a.points+b.points+c.points DESC;
```

Comment: I get this error: 1054 - Unknown column 'player_id' in 'field list' What i'm wondering is, what makes COALESCE differ from IFNULL?

Comment: player_id: I do not have your data model, so my rewrite is a best guess. If you add your data model, the unknown column issue can be identified.

IFNULL is a NULL check, COALESCE is to return the first not NULL value in a list of values. IFNULL is just more specific in your case, and you could see IFNULL as a special case of COALESCE